# Do I have to get the download URL from Firebase Storage? Can't I just save the download URL once I get the image?

Tags: android, performance, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

I would like to ask whether I can use the download URL gotten from the **`UploadTask.TaskSnapshot`** and save it to my Firebase Realtime Database. Or do I have to use the method suggested in the Firebase Docs [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/android/download-files)?

### Upload Image Code (Android)

```
mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();

mStorageRef.child("thumbnails")
          .child("thumbnail")
          .putFile(file)
          .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {

    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot snapshot) {

         //Successfully Got a Thumbnail URL
         mThumbnailURL = snapshot.getMetadata().getDownloadUrl().toString();

         //Upload link to firebase
         FirebaseDatabase.getInstance.getReference()
                 .child("thumnail_links")
                 .push()
                 .putValue(mThumbnailURL);


    }


});
```

### How Firebase suggests downloading the Image

```
mStorageRef.child("thumbnails")
      .child("thumbnail")
      .getDownloadLink()
      .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {

            Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
                   .load(uri.toString())
                   .into(mMyImageView);

        }

});
```

### How I want to download the image

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
       .child("thumbnials")
       .child(pushKey).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                if(dataSnapshot.exists()){

                     String url = (String) dataSnapshot.getValue();
                     Picasso.with(MainActivity.this)
                             .load(url)
                             .into(mMyImageView);

                }

            }

            //...

});
```

**Is there anything wrong with the approach I am using? i.e. do the download URLs change frequently e.t.c...?**

Comment: Either approach seems fine and would work perfectly. But with your approach, it would be slightly difficult to manage the resources say for example if you ever have to delete the thumbnail then you have to write separate logic for deleting from the Realtime Database too. This is actulally more work. right ?

Comment: Actually, I want to implement a list of user's profiles with profile pictures and I want to avoid the extra call of getting the download URL and then loading the image into the ImageView.

Comment: Assuming I already downloaded the list of users from Firebase.